# Subscript error from blau's index using the "diversity" function in R

Tags: r, regression, missing-data

I am trying to get the blau's index using the "diversity" function in R.
However, I constantly get the error using the code and data I suppose to be ok as below.

```
 library(reshape2)
 library(MASS)
 library(proxy)
 library(foreign)
 library(diverse)

 > diversity(data1999[,2:5], type = "blau")
 Error in X[cbind(data[, 5], data[, 4])] <- data[, 3] : 
 subscript out of bounds
```

I get this error **both with and without missing values** in data1999.
In other words, the error above is the same even though I delete the rows including the missing data.

The data1999 with missing values is as below:

```
  Time         ID       X  Gen  Nationality
12/1/1999   34949256    53  M   American
12/1/1999   34949256    59  M   American
12/1/1999   34949256    67  M   American
12/1/1999   34949256    60  M   American
12/1/1999   34949256    58  M   American
12/1/1999   34949256    54  M   
12/1/1999   34949256    57  M   American
12/1/1999   34949256    60  M   
12/1/1999   34949256    46  F   American
12/1/1999   34949256    57  M   American
12/1/1999   34949256    65  M   American
12/1/1999   34949256    66  M   American
12/1/1999   394711590   60  M   American
12/1/1999   394711590   48  M   American
12/1/1999   394711590   70  F   American
12/1/1999   394711590   68  M   Canadian
12/1/1999   394711590   64  M   American
12/1/1999   394711590   68  M   American
12/1/1999   394711590   51  M   American
12/1/1999   394711590   66  M   American
12/1/1999   394711590   53  M   American
12/1/1999   394711590   72  F   American
12/1/1999   394711590   64  M   American
12/1/1999   394711590   69  M   American
12/1/1999   394711590   64  M   
12/1/1999   394711590   59  M   Danish
12/1/1999   401211899   61  M   American
12/1/1999   401211899   67  M   American
12/1/1999   401211899   61  M   American
12/1/1999   401211899   44  M   American
12/1/1999   401211899   74  M   American
12/1/1999   401211899   61  M   American
12/1/1999   401211899   54  M   American
12/1/1999   401211899   42  M   American
12/1/1999   401211899   79  M   American
12/1/1999   401211899   60  M   American
12/1/1999   401211899   77  M   American
12/1/1999   401211899   66  M   American
12/1/1999   401211899   64  M   Canadian
12/1/1999   401211899   50  F   American
12/1/1999   401211899   70  M   American
12/1/1999   401211899   65  F   American
12/1/1999   401211899   80  M   American
12/1/1999   401211899   60  M   American
12/1/1999   401211899   70  M   American
12/1/1999   78638977    64  M   American
12/1/1999   78638977    55  M   American
12/1/1999   78638977    52  M   American
12/1/1999   78638977    58  F   American
12/1/1999   78638977    61  M   American
12/1/1999   78638977    66  M   American
12/1/1999   78638977    57  M   American
12/1/1999   78638977    68  M   American
12/1/1999   78638977    61  M   American
12/1/1999   78638977    58  M   American
12/1/1999   78638977    48  M   American
12/1/1999   78638977    68  M   
12/1/1999   78638977    61  F   American
12/1/1999   78638977    67  M   American
12/1/1999   78638977    58  M   American
12/1/1999   78638977    68  M   American
12/1/1999   78638977    60  F   American
12/1/1999   78638977    64  M   
12/1/1999   78638977    64  F   American
12/1/1999   78638977    68  M   American
12/1/1999   78859127    58  M   American
12/1/1999   78859127    47  M   American
12/1/1999   78859127    54  M   American
12/1/1999   78859127    40  M   American
12/1/1999   78859127    54  M   American
12/1/1999   78859127    66  M   American
12/1/1999   78859127    54  M   American
12/1/1999   78859127    58  M   American
12/1/1999   78859127    68  M   American
12/1/1999   78859127    51  M   American
12/1/1999   78859127    58  M   American
12/1/1999   78859127    56  F   American
12/1/1999   78859127    59  M   American
12/1/1999   78859127    67  M   American
12/1/1999   78859127    67  M   American
12/1/1999   64658968    58  M   American
12/1/1999   64658968    59  M   
12/1/1999   64658968    53  M   American
12/1/1999   64658968    54  M   American
12/1/1999   64658968    58  M   American
12/1/1999   64658968    49  M   American
12/1/1999   64658968    46  M   American
12/1/1999   64658968    65  F   American
12/1/1999   64658968    60  M   American
12/1/1999   64658968    56  M   American
12/1/1999   64658968    64  M   American
12/1/1999   64658968    66  M   American
12/1/1999   64658968    50  M   American
12/1/1999   677010831   51  M   American
12/1/1999   677010831   62  M   American
12/1/1999   677010831   58  M   American
12/1/1999   677010831   64  M   American
12/1/1999   677010831   59  M   American
12/1/1999   677010831   59  M   American
12/1/1999   677010831   59  M   American
12/1/1999   677010831   49  M   American
12/1/1999   677010831   56  M   American
12/1/1999   677010831   64  M   American
12/1/1999   677010831   50  M   
12/1/1999   677010831   69  M   American
12/1/1999   677010831   66  M   American
12/1/1999   677010831   69  M   American
12/1/1999   677010831   59  M   American
12/1/1999   677010831   64  M   
12/1/1999   677010831   57  F   American
12/1/1999   677010831   65  M   American
12/1/1999   677010831   69  M   American
12/1/1999   677010831   67  M   
12/1/1999   677010831   64  M   American
12/1/1999   1089311274  57  M   American
12/1/1999   1089311274  47  M   American
12/1/1999   1089311274  65  M   American
12/1/1999   1089311274  47  F   American
12/1/1999   1089311274  52  M   American
12/1/1999   1089311274  60  M   American
12/1/1999   1089311274  58  M   American
12/1/1999   1089311274  48  F   American
12/1/1999   1089311274  61  M   American
12/1/1999   1089311274  59  M   American
12/1/1999   1089311274  56  M   
12/1/1999   1089311274  64  M   Swiss
12/1/1999   1089311274  69  M   American
12/1/1999   1089311274  56  M   American
12/1/1999   1089311274  67  M   American
12/1/1999   1089311274  71  M   American
12/1/1999   1109612440  61  M   American
12/1/1999   1109612440  66  M   American
12/1/1999   1109612440  61  M   American
12/1/1999   1109612440  60  M   American
12/1/1999   1109612440  54  M   
12/1/1999   1109612440  60  M   American
12/1/1999   1109612440  67  M   American
12/1/1999   1109612440  61  M   American
12/1/1999   1109612440  64  M   
12/1/1999   1109612440  56  M   American
12/1/1999   1109612440  51  M   American
12/1/1999   1109612440  86  M   American
12/1/1999   1109612440  74  M   American
12/1/1999   1109612440  60  F   American
12/1/1999   1109612440  70  M   American
12/1/1999   1109612440  63  M   American
12/1/1999   1109612440  61  M   Belgian
12/1/1999   1109612440  65  M   American
12/1/1999   1109612440  65  M   
12/1/1999   12251873    54  M   American
12/1/1999   12251873    67  M   
12/1/1999   12251873    55  M   American
12/1/1999   12251873    58  M   
12/1/1999   12251873    66  M   
12/1/1999   12251873    56  M   American
12/1/1999   12251873    54  M   American
12/1/1999   12251873    68  M   
12/1/1999   12251873    59  M   American
12/1/1999   12251873    62  M   
12/1/1999   12251873    52  M   American
12/1/1999   12251873    66  M   
12/1/1999   12251873    60  M   American
12/1/1999   12251873    60  M   American
12/1/1999   12251873    55  M   American
12/1/1999   12251873    52  M   
12/1/1999   12251873    67  M   
12/1/1999   12251873    64  M   American
12/1/1999   12251873    68  M   
12/1/1999   12251873    50  M   American
12/1/1999   12251873    67  M   American
12/1/1999   12251873    64  M   
12/1/1999   12251873    59  F   American
12/1/1999   12251873    65  M   American
12/1/1999   175415595   54  M   Brazilian
12/1/1999   175415595   54  M   American
12/1/1999   175415595   57  M   American
12/1/1999   175415595   60  M   American
12/1/1999   175415595   63  M   American
12/1/1999   175415595   61  M   American
12/1/1999   175415595   52  M   American
12/1/1999   175415595   53  M   American
12/1/1999   175415595   68  F   American
12/1/1999   175415595   59  F   American
12/1/1999   175415595   52  M   American
12/1/1999   175415595   44  M   American
12/1/1999   175415595   47  M   American
12/1/1999   175415595   60  M   American
12/1/1999   175415595   57  M   American
12/1/1999   175415595   47  M   American
12/1/1999   175415595   65  M   American
12/1/1999   175415595   61  M   American
12/1/1999   175415595   56  M   
12/1/1999   175415595   52  M   American
12/1/1999   175415595   63  M   American
12/1/1999   175415595   53  F   American
12/1/1999   175415595   54  M   American
12/1/1999   175415595   61  M   American
12/1/1999   44384416    52  M   American
12/1/1999   44384416    64  M   American
12/1/1999   44384416    57  M   American
12/1/1999   44384416    53  M   American
12/1/1999   44384416    55  M   American
12/1/1999   44384416    54  M   American
12/1/1999   44384416    54  M   American
12/1/1999   44384416    80  M   American
12/1/1999   44384416    65  M   American
12/1/1999   44384416    59  M   British
12/1/1999   44384416    71  M   American
12/1/1999   44384416    66  M   American
12/1/1999   2673912732  48  M   American
12/1/1999   2673912732  57  M   American
12/1/1999   2673912732  60  M   American
12/1/1999   2673912732  64  M   British
12/1/1999   2673912732  59  M   American
12/1/1999   2673912732  64  M   
12/1/1999   2673912732  61  M   American
12/1/1999   2673912732  58  M   American
12/1/1999   2673912732  57  M   American
12/1/1999   2673912732  64  M   American
12/1/1999   2673912732  59  M   British
12/1/1999   2673912732  72  M   American
12/1/1999   2673912732  58  F   American
12/1/1999   2673912732  64  M   American
12/1/1999   2698412879  66  M   American
12/1/1999   2698412879  58  M   American
12/1/1999   2698412879  66  M   American
12/1/1999   2698412879  60  M   American
12/1/1999   2698412879  64  M   American
12/1/1999   2698412879  51  M   American
12/1/1999   2698412879  37  M   
12/1/1999   274882235   60  M   American
12/1/1999   274882235   61  M   American
12/1/1999   274882235   65  F   Australian
12/1/1999   274882235   67  M   American
12/1/1999   274882235   65  M   American
12/1/1999   274882235   66  M   American
12/1/1999   274882235   68  M   American
12/1/1999   274882235   70  M   American
12/1/1999   274882235   58  F   American
12/1/1999   274882235   67  M   
12/1/1999   274882235   69  M   American
12/1/1999   422076955   50  M   American
12/1/1999   422076955   45  M   
12/1/1999   422076955   70  M   American
12/1/1999   422076955   67  M   American
12/1/1999   422076955   61  M   American
12/1/1999   422076955   44  M   American
12/1/1999   422076955   55  M   American
12/1/1999   422076955   71  M   American
12/1/1999   422076955   38  F   American
12/1/1999   422076955   60  M   American
12/1/1999   422076955   64  M   American
12/1/1999   422076955   54  F   
12/1/1999   422076955   63  F   American
12/1/1999   422076955   57  M   American
12/1/1999   422076955   66  M   American
12/1/1999   422076955   57  M   American
12/1/1999   422076955   57  M   American
12/1/1999   423917141   51  M   American
12/1/1999   423917141   56  M   American
12/1/1999   423917141   57  M   American
12/1/1999   423917141   58  M   American
12/1/1999   423917141   67  M   American
12/1/1999   423917141   64  M   American
12/1/1999   423917141   64  M   
12/1/1999   423917141   55  F   American
12/1/1999   423917141   68  M   American
12/1/1999   423917141   61  F   American
12/1/1999   423917141   58  M   
12/1/1999   423917141   50  F   American
12/1/1999   423917141   64  M   Chinese
12/1/1999   423917141   60  M   American
12/1/1999   423917141   64  M   American
12/1/1999   423917141   53  F   American
12/1/1999   423917141   57  M   American
12/1/1999   423917141   53  F   American
12/1/1999   423917141   68  M   American
12/1/1999   423917141   70  M   American
12/1/1999   423917141   56  M   American
12/1/1999   423917141   61  M   American
12/1/1999   423917141   59  M   American
12/1/1999   423917141   67  M   American
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of `diverse`:

> The argument "data", also accepts a dataframe with three columns in
>   the following order: entity, category and value.

So, when given a dataframe, it expects three **and only three columns**. By putting `data1999[,2:5]` you are selecting four columns, which this function does not handle well at all (a more meaningful error would be great in this case...)

Try `diversity(data1999[,2:4], type="blau")` or `diversity(data1999[,3:5], type="blau")` and you'll get what you want (I hope, I wasn't able to interpret any of that).

Comment: Thank you so much! It was my unexpectedly shaded part that I did not even realize. Thank you!